# How do I call dispose() on a JMenuItem?

Tags: java, swing, dispose, actionlistener, jmenuitem

I'm trying to write code so that when a user clicks the 'File' tab and selects 'Exit', it exits the whole window I've built.

I am trying to use the `dispose();` method, but it gives me the error 
"The method dispose() is undefined for the type new ActionListener()"

Heres the code

```
public static void addLayouts(){

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setTitle("IPFinder");
        GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(frame.getContentPane());
        groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGap(0, 384, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGap(0, 362, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(groupLayout);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(mnFile);



        JMenu mnEdit = new JMenu("Edit");
        menuBar.add(mnEdit);

        JMenuItem mntmCopyResults = new JMenuItem("Copy Results");
        mnEdit.add(mntmCopyResults);

        JMenu mnAbout = new JMenu("About");
        menuBar.add(mnAbout);

        JMenuItem mntmAboutIpfinder = new JMenuItem("About IPFinder");
        mnAbout.add(mntmAboutIpfinder);
        frame.setVisible(true);



        JMenuItem mntmExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        mntmExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dispose();
            }
        });
        mnFile.add(mntmExit);


    }
```

I speant about 2 hours on google trying to figure it but i can't get it to work.

I've exhausted all my options at this point so I came here. 
Any help is apreciated.

Comment: ... I feel incredibly stupid. I completely put it past me that I'm actually closing the entire window, so JFrame, being it, should be closed. I apologize. But I just learned a lot from this. Thank you all, I would give everyone a check but I can only accept one. Thanks again.Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dispose()` should be called on `JFrame` or `JDialog`, and not on `ActionListener`.

> but it gives me the error "The method dispose() is undefined for the type new ActionListener()"

Exactly. `ActionListener` has only one method `actionPerformed()`.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html

Answer (score 5):

Use `ClassName.this.dispose()` if your class extends `JFrame` or `JDialog` instead of simply calling `dispose()` or `frame.dispose()` if you have a `frame` variable of such type. In your case it is the second option: `frame.dispose();`

This way, you tell the compiler that you are calling the `dispose()` of a `Window` subtype and not of the anonymous implementation of an `ActionListener`, which doesn't have a `dispose()` anyway.

Comment: Then I believe you. Deleting my comment.

Comment: Don't believe me, just try it :)

Comment: Not near a copy of the JDK right now. That's why I said 'can't confirm right now.'

Answer (score 2):

As I have seen you have defined

```
frame = new JFrame();
```

Your class does not extend `JFrame`. So when you call `dispose` it throws error since `ActionListener` class does not have such method.

So use the component which you want to dispose.

```
Example: frame.dispose();
```